# Moving from stack to heap, vector and array

Tags: c++, memory

I made two simple programs where I try to move things from different memories.

One is using a vector stored on the heap, the other a array. After running thoose examples, I don't understand the output.

I like to see the move operator as a swap between pointers, i might be wrong but if a heap ptr receives a pointer from the stack, when it gets cleared, the heap ptr will point to nothing valuable unless a deap copy is done ?

With vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Bitmap {

    Bitmap() {}

    Bitmap(string n) : name(n) {}

    Bitmap(const Bitmap& other) {
        name = other.name;
        std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Bitmap& operator=(const Bitmap& other) {
        name = other.name;
        std::cout << "assignment operator" << std::endl;
    }

    Bitmap(Bitmap&& other) {
        name = move(other.name);
        std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    string name;
};

struct BitmapContainer {

    BitmapContainer() {}

    std::vector<Bitmap> data;
};

int main() {

    BitmapContainer stackContainer;
    BitmapContainer* heapContainer = new BitmapContainer();

    Bitmap test;
    Bitmap test2;
    Bitmap* test3 = new Bitmap();

    std::cout << "only on stack" << std::endl;
    stackContainer.data.push_back(move(test));

    std::cout << "stack to heap" << std::endl;
    heapContainer->data.push_back(move(test2));

    std::cout << "heap to heap" << std::endl;
    heapContainer->data.push_back(move(*test3));
}
```

output:

```
only on stack
move constructor
stack to heap
move constructor
heap to heap
move constructor
copy constructor
```

The 2 first moves imply it's possible to move object from one memory to the other, even if my vector is on the heap, the first one should have failed like the second one. And I don't get why i got a copy constructor called at the end.

Now if I use array instead:

```
struct BitmapContainer {

    BitmapContainer() {}

    std::array<Bitmap, 2> data;
};

int main() {

    BitmapContainer stackContainer;
    BitmapContainer* heapContainer = new BitmapContainer();

    Bitmap test;
    Bitmap test2;
    Bitmap* test3 = new Bitmap();

    std::cout << "only on stack" << std::endl;
    stackContainer.data[0] = move(test);

    std::cout << "stack to heap" << std::endl;
    heapContainer->data[0] = move(test2);

    std::cout << "heap to heap" << std::endl;
    heapContainer->data[1] = move(*test3);
}
```

output:

```
only on stack
assignment operator
stack to heap
assignment operator
heap to heap
assignment operator
```

Only copies, I don't know why.

Comment: _The 2 first moves imply it's possible to move object from one memory to the other, even if my vector is on the heap, the first one should have failed like the second one._ Sorry, I don't follow the logic here.

Comment: ```Test``` is a local variable, allocated on the stack, I move it to a vector on the heap. My point is if there are no deep copies, when the stack gets cleared the vector should reference an object that might have been destroyed.

Comment: _the vector should reference an object that might have been destroyed_ Why? Where, inside `Bitmap` do you see any such reference? Vector does not store pointers/references to objects, it stores objects themselves. You just move a _contents_ of `test` into some vector element.

Comment: The object ```test``` itself needs to be stored somewhere, at start it's in the stack. If the move just assign its address to the element inside the vector (no copy whatsoever, like move implies), if the stack clears its content ```test``` should be gone.

Comment: _If the move just assign its address_ Where did you get that from? "Move" does whatever move constructor does. I don't see any address asisgnment in the move constructor of `Bitmap`. Move constructor simply creates a new object, and moves, into it, the contents of the original object.

Comment: I would just add one note, since I have a feeling you don't understand things correctly. As you say _The object test itself needs to be stored somewhere, at start it's in the stack._ - Once the object is created at some place in memory, it stays there until it is destructed. There is no way how to move that object somewhere else. Move operations,such as _move-construction_, does not move the original object anywhere. It just creates a new object and do whatever is defined in its body. Typically, this "moves the contents" of that object and what does it mean is given by semantics of the class.

Comment: Move does not imply that no copy is created. It just says that the contents of one object is moved to another. In the worst case a move is just a copy. But the compiler can optimize a move differently then a copy.

Comment: I aggree with you now, but the worst case scenario happens for all basics type (only vector and string in my opinion are good), if you look at my screenshot, you will see that all the data are dupplicated, even if the array was allocated on the heap

Comment: @DraykoonD In extreme cases, move operation can be even slower than copy. For instance, if you copy short strings that apply _small/short string optimization_, you just need to copy characters. But typical implementations of move also sets the move-from string into an empty state. Which represents some additional operations. Generally, no one guarantees that move will be faster than copy. This is imporatant for classes that involve some resource management (such as dynamically allocated memory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And I don't get why I got a copy constructor called at the end.

The copy constructor is used when the vector *reallocates*, which means, that it's capacity is full and there is no more space to insert a new (pushed back) element at the end. Reallocation basically allocates a new memory space and "moves" the actual elements from the original memory.

However, this "move" is realized with copy construtor in your case. The reason is that your move constructor is not `noexcept`, and `std::vector` prefers *strong exception guarantee* over performance here.

If you make your `Bitmap::Bitmap(Bitmap&&)` constructor `noexcept`, move constructor [will be used instead](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TUldmjGCb9TgZf92). You can safely do this since the move constructor of `std::string` is [guaranteed to be `noexcept`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#3).

To make the comparison fair, either use different vectors in both cases, or `reserve` a memory for both elements in advance.

---

As for arrays, you don't define a *move assignment operator* for `Bitmap`. Consequently, there is no other option than to use a defined *copy assignment operator* for assigning array elements. Using `std::move` cannot change anything about it.

Comment: If we don't take the allocation of the vectors into account, when I move an object from stack memory to the heap, does it imply an internal copy ?

Comment: @DraykoonD No, there is no copy as long as a move constructor is defined in this case. Note that C++ does not define _stack_ nor _heap_, these are just implementation details. You simply "move" an object (we should say move its contents) from one place into another.

Comment: ok for the c++ standard, but internally ? It's two separate memory, if it doesn't copy the content, when the stack is cleared the pointer shouldn't be available anymore, at this point it's just gessing

Comment: @DraykoonD Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking about. An object is an object no matter where is it stored. You can copy or move its contents with no difference. Only difference is that the object on the stack (with automatic storage duration) is destructed automatically.

Comment: I might be wrong, but i like to see the move operator as a swap between pointers. If a heap ptr receives a stack ptr via a move, when we leave the scope. The object referenced should be destroyed hence, the heap ptr point to nothing. I thought that using move between memories wasn't a good idea unless it performs deep copy internally.

Comment: @DraykoonD _I might be wrong, but i like to see the move operator as a swap between pointers._ That very much depends on where this pointer points to.

Comment: @DraykoonD I would suggest to create a simpler example of what you are asking for. You basically ask many questions at once and it's hard to understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Your `vector` is on the stack or heap but the contents of the `vector` are always on the heap which is why there is no difference between your first two cases.

With `array` the contents are part of the structure so if the `array` is on the stack the elements are also on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add my personal view on the solution brought by Daniel

Move is not just a swap of pointer between two objects. It will call recursively the move constructor on all its member, at the end resulting in moving basic type (int, array, float) which will result in a copy. So if you move an object allocated on the stack to a vector you will copy all the basic types contained in the object.

The move is only usefull for Types who only leaves on the heap (string, vector, Object*), there you might expect the smart swap of pointers.

If we take this example and look at the memory footPrint, in the end i duppilcated the array in the heap memory.

```
struct Bitmap {
    array<float, 100000> data;
};


int main() {

    std::vector<Bitmap> bitmapContainer;

    Bitmap stackObject;
    Bitmap* heapObject = new Bitmap();

    std::cout << "here " << std::endl;
    auto c = getchar();

    bitmapContainer.push_back(move(stackObject));
    bitmapContainer.push_back(move(*heapObject));

    std::cout << "after " << std::endl;
    c = getchar();
}
```

before move 400kb on the stack 400k on the heap

[image]

after Move 400 kb on the stack 1200 on the heap

[image]